# How to subtract 1 from an int

Tags: objective-c

How do I subtract 1 from an int

Comment: I don't know how anybody could argue this is "not a real question".  OK it's about as basic as you can get, but it's still a question with an obvious (well several) answer.

Comment: Yeah its pretty basic - turns out there was another problem is my code and that is why it wasn't working.  However I still think the question is valid and useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int i = 15;
i--;
```

You can find more helpful information here:

[Objective-C Arthimetic Operators](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions#Objective-C_Arithmetic_Operators)

Answer (score 4):

i don't know objectice-c, but shouldn't this be:

```
myint = myint - 1;
```

or, more easy:

```
myint--;
```

Comment: or `--myint;` - thanks jeremy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
int x=2;
x = x-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int foo = 42;
int bar = foo - 1;
```